# segmentation fault: core dumped error in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that stores and prints all lines that are longer than 80 characters. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

//prints all lines that are greater than 80 characters in length.
#define MAXLENGTH 1000
#define MAXLINES 100

main(){
    printf("Enter stuff\n");
    char cline[MAXLINES][MAXLENGTH];
    int a, b, input, loop1, loop, length, line = 0, loop2;
    bool lines[MAXLINES];
    for(a = 0; a < MAXLINES; a++)
        for(b = 0; b < MAXLENGTH; b++)
            cline[a][b] = ' ';
    for (loop = 0; loop < MAXLINES; loop++)
        lines[loop] = false;
    while((input = getchar()) != EOF){
        for(loop = 0; loop < MAXLENGTH; loop++){
            cline[line][loop] += (char)input;
            length++;
            if(input == '\n')
                break;
        }
        if(length > 80)
            lines[line] = true;
        line++;
    }
    for(loop1 = 0; loop1 < MAXLINES; loop1++){
        lines[loop] = false;
    while((input = getchar()) != EOF){
        for(loop = 0; loop < MAXLENGTH; loop++){
            cline[line][loop] += (char)input;
            length++;
            if(input == '\n')
                break;
        }
        if(length > 80)
            lines[line] = true;
        line++;
    }
    for(loop1 = 0; loop1 < MAXLINES; loop1++){
        if (lines[loop] == true)
            for(loop2 = 0; loop2 < MAXLENGTH; loop2++)
                putchar(cline[loop][loop2]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

If there is a line that is longer than 80 characters, I get this error:
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)

And if there isn't a line that's longer than 80, I get a whole bunch of random characters like this:

```
Enter stuff
hello
       �������������������������������������������������������������������������

fazer@Deamons-head:~/Programs/C$ Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And then the segmentation fault error.
The 'little question mark characters' appear different amounts depending on the length of the input (both number of lines and length of each line).

I need help understanding why, because I've initialized my character and array and declared memory to it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not a good idea to put a 100,000 byte array (cline) on the stack. If you really, really need a data structure of this size (and you probably don't) then you should dynamically allocate it with malloc.

Comment: Please spend some time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: variable "length" is not initialized.

Comment: `length++;` uninitialised variable.

Comment: As suggested, a debugger would be helpful for you here. There are too many issues with your code to give you a simple answer. But for starters your first `while` loop is just completely wrong. The `getchar` is only called once per `while` iteration but the `for` loop inside it keeps storing the same `input` value. And I'm not sure why you are using `+=` rather than just `=` to store the `input` value.

Comment: `cline[line][loop] += (char)input;` followed by an unchecked `line++` when the array limit is `100` is going to overflow if you type more then 100 characters.

Comment: length is initialized as an integer. Any sites I should go to for debugger's and tutorials? Thank you for pointing out the while loop and for loop mistake, I'm looking into that and I think that that was the error.  I'm using += rather than = because I want to store the whole string not just the individual characters. The 100 is for the number of lines not number of characters. I assume that no one is going to be typing more than 100 lines of text.

Comment: 1) `if (lines[loop] == true)...putchar(cline[loop][loop2]);` should be `if (lines[loop1] == true)...putchar(cline[loop1][loop2]);`

Comment: 2) `for(loop = 0; loop < MAXLENGTH; loop++){
            cline[line][loop] += (char)input;` meant fill `' ' + input`

Comment: 3) `for(loop1 = 0; loop1 < MAXLINES; loop1++){
        lines[loop] = false;...` Have duplicate

Comment: Thanks for the help @BLUEPIXY and AlanAu. got it working. Using += was a mistake, I should have been using = . and the printing mistake in the index variable that BLUPIXY noted was invaluable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems in your code. As mentioned in the comments length is unitialized, a compiler with the -Wall option would have told you that and you should not allocate too much memory from the stack and use malloc/calloc instead, in this we are not crashing the program though. After you have an indentation/brackets problem which makes it complicated to fully understand what the code is supposed to do, and I belived you have typos inside your two last for loops, `loop1` is incremented but `loop` and `loop2` are used.

Finally the segmentation fault probably comes from the wrong usage of `getchar`, you are incrementing `line` each time a char is read from the `stdin`, in the end you probably have more than 100 lines with 1 char in it, you should use `fgets` which will directly read a line.

Here is some code that I think does what you want

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

//prints all lines that are greater than 80 characters in length.
#define MAXLENGTH 1000
#define MAXLINES 100

int main(){
    printf("Enter stuff\n");
    char cline[MAXLINES][MAXLENGTH];
    int a, b, loop1, loop, line = 0;
    bool lines[MAXLINES];
    for(a = 0; a < MAXLINES; a++)
        for(b = 0; b < MAXLENGTH; b++)
            cline[a][b] = ' ';
    for (loop = 0; loop < MAXLINES; loop++)
        lines[loop] = false;
    while((fgets(cline[line], MAXLENGTH, stdin)) != NULL){
        if(strlen(cline[line]) > 80)
            lines[line] = true;
        line++;
        if(line == MAXLINES) break;
    }
    for(loop1 = 0; loop1 < MAXLINES; loop1++){
        if (lines[loop1] == true)
            printf("%s\n", cline[loop1]);
    }
}
```

One last thing, a core dump is a copy of the memory used by your program when it crashed, a debugger like gdb can read it and you would have found that `line` was way over `MAXLINES`.

Comment: Thank you, your code worked for me. But why does everyone think that length is uninitialized? It is initialized as an integer.

Comment: In C when you declare a variable on the stack (a local variable) it has the value of whatever was on the stack at the that moment, which can be anything. int length just declares an integer, int length = 0 declares an integer equal to zero.